# I need help to code this variable calculation

Tags: pine-script

I am looking for help to code this variable:

N = number of highest highs / lowest lows since the trade entry point.

Many thanks to you

'''''''''''''''''''''

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: I searched in the pinescript tutorials but did not find 
Being a beginner I don't know which disputes and other use

Comment: What is your definition of a highest bar ? For me there is only ONE highest bar since your entry point., the same for your lowest bar... N = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of the number of highest high you need to create a `var` variable. A `var` variable is a variable that maintains its value between bars. Then we update the variable if the current `high` is higher the `highest high`.

I created a script that plots the `highest high` and `lowest low` as lines. It also prints the `N` variable on the right. You have the code the entry point by yourself, but here is a base on have the keep track of the `highest high`

[image: trading view graph]

code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("number of highest highs and lowest low", overlay = true)

var int num_highest_high = 0 //times
var int num_lowest_low = 0 //times

var float previous_highest_high = na //price
var float previous_lowest_low = na //price

if(na(previous_highest_high) or high > previous_highest_high) //na the first time
    previous_highest_high := high
    num_highest_high += 1

if(na(previous_lowest_low) or low < previous_lowest_low) //na the first time
    previous_lowest_low := low
    num_lowest_low += 1

float n = num_highest_high / num_lowest_low

plot(previous_highest_high, "previous highest high", color=color.green)
plot(previous_lowest_low, "previous lowest low", color=color.red)
plotchar(n, "N", "") //to display the value in the "Data Window"
```